What are thet pros/cons when implementing AD using a subdomain of the public domain name versus a totally separate root domain?
In our existing domain controller we are using our public domain name xyz.net, and this domain is publically registered, and we are aware of the split DNS issue. Our plan is to modernize the domain controller server and an opportunity to fix the situation.
Definitely the .local is not an option since it is a deprecated and not recommended.
So we are thinking of two options, either we go with corp.xyz.net as a root forest for our AD or we purchase a different domain such as xyz.network (note that .network tld is publicly available for purchase hence no ownership issues for future).
The question is, what are the pros and cons between the subdomain and or a totally different domain? Any advice from your experience why one would decide to go to subdomain vs different domain in domain controller?
Appreciate your help
Thanks
